# Rename a file in AWS Lambda using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, fs

I am trying to rename a file currently stored in AWS Lambda /tmp/ directory.

I have tried the code below, but it states it cannot find the file. Even though it lists tmp as the path

```
//Rename file
        fs.renameSync('/tmp/' + newFilename, '/tmp/' + oldFilename);
        console.log('File renamed from ' + oldFilename + ' to ' + newFilename);
```

I run the main function as async, with my other fs functions looking like

```
const unlink2 = util.promisify(fs.unlink);
        await unlink2('/tmp/' + newFilename)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('File has been deleted from /tmp/');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Error', err);
            });
```

So not sure which way press ahead here. Can anyone help with the correct code/procedure?

Comment: You are trying to rename a file after you delete it?

Comment: No, rename it, do some stuff. I always empty the /tmp/ after I finish up, if the Lambda gets recycled it is just an extra precaution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback).

The old path should be first, the new path is the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

`.then().catch()` are used without `await`, so it's either:

```
unlink2(...).then(...).catch(...)
```

or

```
try {
  await unlink2(...)
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
doNextOperation()
```

In your example code, you write rename (newPath, oldPath), it should be the other way around, that's probably why the file can't be found:

```
fs.renameSync(oldPath, newPath)
```

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_renamesync_oldpath_newpath